# How to search multiple data with high performance in mysql query browser?

Tags: mysql-5.5, query-performance

I'm using MySQL Query Browser and having two tables. One is `tblbusiness` having records 1.4 million with one of the columns `zipcode` and other table `tblbusinessnew` having 300,000 records with columns `pincode`, `longitude` and `latitude`.

```
SELECT tblbusiness.*, 
       tblbusinessnew.zipcode, tblbusinessnew.longitude, tblbusinessnew.latitude 
FROM tblbusiness, tblbusinessnew 
WHERE tblbusiness.zipcode=tblbusinessnew.pincode;
```

If I search for few records it is fine but mysql query browser suddenly dissapper when I run this query because one `zipcode` of `tblbusiness` have multiple `pincode` in `tblbusinessnew`. Please fix this problem.

Comment: Do you have indexes on each of the 2 joined columns? How many rows will the query return? Are there text columns in the results?

Comment: I think you should provide the `CREATE TABLE` statements and the execution plan.

Comment: @ypercube: Thnx for suggestion. Because of huge data CREATE TABLE for selected records also doesnot work. I have not used indexes and I will try with creating indexes. Millions of records should returned by this query. No there are no any text columns in the results.

Comment: Have you really tried `SHOW CREATE TABLE tblbusiness;` ?

Comment: @ypercube: Hurray! i solved my task. By creating index of all the fields above query executed successfully in 35 minutes and I saved 2334039 records in csv file directly without inserting into table. Thanx a lot for suggestion.

Comment: @ypercube: Actually show create I don't understand please make it clear. I think logic is to insert the resulted data come from select query into some new table. Example: INSERT INTO tblNew(fields)(SELECT query); Am I right?